# Running a Java Program from jar file not working if another package is used, classpath set

Tags: java

I am importing one class(it is not there in the default jvm) from one jar package and using it in another package. *like* I have a class program1.class in package package1 and I am importing this class from another programme program2 in package package2.

```
package package1;
public class Program1
{
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

and importing this class in

```
package package2;
import package1.Program1;
public class Program2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("I am in programme2");
        System.out.println("I am in programme 1"+new Program1().sayHello());
    }
}
```

I have compiled the program1 and packaged it by
    javac -d . Program1.java
    jar cf Pack1.jar package1

and second programme by
    javac -d . Program2.java
    jar cfm Pack2.jar Manifest.txt package2

my manifest file is

```
Main-Class: package2.Program2
```

now I am running the programme as
    java -classpath path/to/Pack1.jar -jar Pack2.jar

it is giving me error as:
    I am in Program2
    No class def found error Package1/Program1

If I am running it by specifying the  Class as
    java -classpath path/to/Pack1.jar;path/to/Pack2(UnJar'ed) Pack2.program2
it is working which is very strange

Means there is a different between specifying the class file containing the main and specifying the jar file of the program.
I have already made sure that I have set Main-Class is set correctly in Manifest.mf, moreover the classpath for pack2 is also specified
So why this error

Comment: have you considered using maven to package your project and use the assembly plugin to create a jar-with-dependencies? I'm sure figuring out the details of this stuff is very interesting but on the other hand maven does it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the -jar option, all other classpath options are ignored. Thats why you are getting a NoClassDefFoundException.

See [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) here.

Here is the relevant note from that link --

-jar  Execute a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. In order for this option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a line of the form Main-Class: classname. Here, classname identifies the class having the public static void main(String[] args) method that serves as your application's starting point.

See the Jar tool reference page and the Jar trail of the Java Tutorial for information about working with Jar files and Jar-file manifests. When you use this option, **the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.**

The fix would be to include the Class-Path in your jar manifest.

Comment: If the classpath option is ignored then how would the system find out the jar on which the program is dependent ? Suppose I write a program dependent on classes packaged as another jar but when I distribute my program I would not know where the dependent jar could be in another system. I should just depend on the CLASSPATH environment variable which is where the system would search. If when using jar option there is no way for the system to search for dependent jar file then how would I even distribute my program to be run on another system

Comment: Raks -- you are correct. When you are distributing an executable jar, you have to package all the classes that the jar file is dependent on within that jar itself .. there's tools that help you do this -- jarjar or onejar etc.

Comment: Somehow it is unbelievable, Its a major deployment headache. My idea of deployment is to have all kinds of thirdparty libraries be put in a thirdparty directory and then multiple java programs refer to this single repository. This way the thirdparty library can be updated independent of the main program and even deployed independently